# how to use preg_replace to replace all ocurrences of a given pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I have a pattern (a slash followed by 1 or more dashes) inside strings that could occur many times like

```
/hi/--hello/-hi
```

I want to replace it with

```
/hi/hello/hi
```

I have tried

```
$str = preg_replace('/\/-+/', '/', $subject);
```

but this does not seem to be working properly. Am I missing something. I use http://www.debuggex.com/ to test my regex and `\/-+` does not seem to match the string.

Comment: This replace should work. Are you sure to display $str (and not $subject). For php it is better to use regex101.com or regex.larsolavtorvik.com (are designed for php)

Comment: This seems to work properly for me with those exact strings.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: works for me too at debuggex.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte debuggex does support PCRE now, so as long as you pick the right flavor, it should be fine.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. It is /hi/--hello/-hi

Comment: And preg replace seems to work but not debuggex.

Comment: @aresnelupin still, debuggex matches them all

Comment: @m.buettner http://i.imgur.com/4bvQWqC.png

Comment: perhaps I am confused and yellow means it matches ?

Comment: I prefer to use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: @aresnelupin yes, exactly

Comment: Thank you guys I was confused. How can we mark the question as answered in order not to waste people's time anymore.

Comment: you can accept Casimir's answer. it seems to be correct. or delete the question.

Comment: @bansi RegExr uses ActionScript and hence the ECMAScript flavor. It's therefore not appropriate for PHP testing.

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks for the info. I don't use tools to write my regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work in debuggex.com is that you don't have to put the delimiters on this site.

Remove the slashes at the begining and at the end from the input box.

Write only: `\/-+`  or  `/-+` since you don't need to escape the slashes.